# denyAll() redirect to login url but I need another url

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

This code blocked properly every request which is finished on XHTML but I would like redirect the request to url like "/spring/denied" not "/spring/login" which is setted on method formLogic()

```
        http
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/spring/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/spring/loginProcess")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/spring/main")
            .failureUrl("/spring/login?login_error=1")
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/spring/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/spring/logoutSuccess")
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/spring/**/*.xhtml").denyAll()
        .and()


        // Disable CSRF (won't work with JSF) but ensure last HTTP POST request is saved
        // See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-2498

        .csrf().disable()
        .requestCache()
            .requestCache(new HttpSessionRequestCache());
```

So, I think there will be theses possible scenes:

1. Someone intent to access to any real XHTML file directly (/main/index.xhtml): Behavior: Request blocked and redirected to *denied url*, if someone wish it , he must interact using right flow definition (p.e. /main, /groups....)
2. Someone intent to access to secured url without right permissions or anonymous (p.e. /admin, /authenticate...): Behavior: Spring security intercept request and redirect to *login url*
3. Some intent to access to secured url with right permissions (p.e /admin, /authenticate....): Behavior: Spring security grants access and spring web flow make its task redirecting properly
4. Someone intent to access unknown url (p.e. /ImAUnluckyGuyAndThisUrlIsUnreal): Behavior: Spring webflow intercept request and redirect to last flow known.

Using XML configuration above cases are right. Furthermore I used spring webflow  2.3 instead 2.4.0RC1 and Annotations configurations

**Case 1**: Adding this code on web.xml, I don't know how replace fot annotations configurations

```
    <security-constraint>
          <display-name>Restrict direct access to XHTML access</display-name>
          <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>XHTML</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
          </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint />
  </security-constraint>
```

**Case 4**: Adding this code on a abstract flow definition, I don't know if doesn't work on Spring webflow 2.4.0RC1 or it's a annotations configuration problem.

```
    <global-transitions>
       <transition on-exception="org.springframework.webflow.engine.NoMatchingTransitionException" to="handlingViewState">
        <evaluate expression="handlingBean.handle(flowExecutionException)">    </evaluate>
    </transition>
</global-transitions>
```

**Case 2 and 3**: These are not problematic. if user is authenticated and doesn't got permissions is redirected using **.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/spring/denied")** or user is anonymous is redirected to **loginPage()**

**Webflow configuration**

```
@Bean
public FlowExecutor flowExecutor() {
    return getFlowExecutorBuilder(flowRegistry())
            .addFlowExecutionListener(new FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener())
            .addFlowExecutionListener(new SecurityFlowExecutionListener())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public FlowDefinitionRegistry flowRegistry() {
    return getFlowDefinitionRegistryBuilder(flowBuilderServices())
            .setBasePath("/WEB-INF/flows")
            .addFlowLocationPattern("/**/*-flow.xml")
            .build();
}

@Bean
public FlowBuilderServices flowBuilderServices() {
    return getFlowBuilderServicesBuilder().setDevelopmentMode(true).build();
}
```

}

**MVC configuration**

```
@Autowired
private WebFlowConfig webFlowConfig;

@Bean
public FlowHandlerMapping flowHandlerMapping() {
    FlowHandlerMapping mapping = new FlowHandlerMapping();
    mapping.setOrder(1);
    mapping.setFlowRegistry(this.webFlowConfig.flowRegistry());
    /* If no flow matches, map the path to a view, e.g. "/intro" maps to a view named "intro" */
    mapping.setDefaultHandler(new UrlFilenameViewController());
    return mapping;
}

@Bean
public FlowHandlerAdapter flowHandlerAdapter() {
    JsfFlowHandlerAdapter adapter = new JsfFlowHandlerAdapter();
    adapter.setFlowExecutor(this.webFlowConfig.flowExecutor());
    return adapter;
}

@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver faceletsViewResolver() {
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    resolver.setViewClass(JsfView.class);
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".xhtml");
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter simpleControllerHandlerAdapter() {
    return new SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter();
}
```

Comment: `.failureUrl("/spring/denied?login_error=1")` does not work?

Comment: No @Matt, /spring/index.xhtml is redirected to /spring/login?execution=e3s1

Comment: Oh I see now, you redirect to /spring/login if authorization fails, so it is looping back if they do not succeed in login, but if you are located on /spring/login and you fail, you want to break the loop and go to /spring/denied

Comment: @Matt, the problem arised when I've updated the project to use \@Configuration and Spring 2.4.0.RC1 instead of web.xml and SWF 2.3.0, because before I supplied this behavior using this code and SWF always redirect to denied page 

 <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Restrict direct access to XHTML access</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>XHTML</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>

Comment: If the request is not XHTML, then you would expect to redirect to /spring/login?

Comment: @Javakid I edited question with possible ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is multiple `<http>` [HttpSecurity] configuration and you need to provide a custom AuthenticationEntryPoint implementation.

Below is the HttpSecurity configuration for case 1. (I hope you can come-up with a configuration for case 2 & 3 and you can use the one you already have.)

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)                                                        
public static class XHTMLAccessDenyWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/spring/**/*.xhtml")
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new AccessDenyEntryPoint()).and()                
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/spring/**/*.xhtml").denyAll();
    }
}
```

**Note:** The order of the above security configuration should be higher than the security configuration for case 2 & 3; therefore, `@Order` is used.

Custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint` implementation would simply redirect the request to /spring/deny page as below

```
public class AccessDenyEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/spring/denied").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```